# AngularJS - pass parameter from ng-repeat to controller from custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom AngularJS directive, which is rendering a ng-repeat. In this ng-repeat I want to pass one element to a function. The function is called, but item is undefined.

Important: I get my persons form a rest-call.

```
//Inside the template
<ul class="list-group" data-ng-repeat="person in persons track by $index">
<li>
... ng-click=fn(person) ...
</li>
</ul>
```

This is the function I like to pass the person.

```
//in outside controller    
$scope.showPerson = function (item) {
    console.log(item) // this is undefined
}
```

My directive looks like this:

```
directive('custom', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            persons: "=persons",
            fn: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: "/views/templates/persons.html"
    };
});
```

I call my directive like this:

```
<custom persons="persons" fn="showPerson()"></custom>
```

Any ideas why item is undefined? The only thing I can imagine is a timing issue, because the directive fires before the array of persons is filled (from the rest call).

Comment: scope: {
            persons: "=",
}

One thing that quickly stands out, compared to a directive that I created.

Comment: You can write both (In case of <custom p="persons", you can write persons: "=p",).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions passed to isolated scope have a peculiarity, when accepting arguments. For starters, define the argument in the HTML:

```
<custom persons="persons" fn="showPerson(x)"></custom>
```

Note the argument name: `x`. Now from within the template of the directive (this is the peculiarity):

```
<button ng-click="fn({x: person})" ...>
```

Where `x` is the name of the argument defined above.